# Poisson distribution question attempt

Tags: probability

I usually find these sort of questions straightforward but this was worded pretty vaguely as I haven't really come across anything like it.

I answered all the questions but I'm not sure about the accuracy of the answers.

I was just wondering about the correct method to go about attempting such questions and if I was on the correct track.

> **The American Charted Insurance Company finds that 0.02% of the population (from which its policy holders are drawn) dies from a certain disease each year. The company insures 10000 people against this disease. Analysts in the company have decided that a Poisson distribution is appropriate to model the occurrence of the disease.**
>
> **i) What is the mean number of people insured against this disease with British Chartered who will die from the disease in:**
>
> **a) the next year?**
>
> $$10000 \times 0.0002 = 2$$
>
> **b) the next two years?**
>
> $$10000 \times 0.0004 = 4$$
>
> **ii) Find the probability that British Chartered will pay out on more than two cases of death in:**
>
> **a) the next year**
>
> $$P(X=r) = m^r \times \frac{e^{-m}}{r!}$$
>   $$P(X=r) = 2^1 \times \frac{e^{-2}}{1!}$$
>   $$P(X=r) = 0.271$$
>
> **b) the next two years**
>
> $$P(X=r) = m^r \times \frac{e^{-m}}{r!}$$
>   $$P(X=r) = 4^2 \times \frac{e^{-4}}{2!}$$
>   $$P(X=r) = 0.147$$
>
> **c) the next five years**
>
> $$P(X=r) = m^r \times \frac{e^{-m}}{r!}$$
>   $$P(X=r) = 10^5 \times \frac{e^{-10}}{5!}$$
>   $$P(X=r) = 0.038$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In (ii), you say you're calculating $P(X=r)$ (where for some unknown reason you seem to be taking $r$ to be the number of years).  But the question asks about $P(X > 2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $$P(X=r)=m^r\cdot{e^{-m}\over r!}$$ gives the probability that *exactly* $r$ deaths occurred where $m$ is the average number of deaths over the time period considered.

In part b), you want to calculate the probability  that *more* than 2 deaths occurred in two years.  Here,  $m=4$ (two years and on average two deaths per year).  More than 2 could be exactly 3, or exactly 4, or ...

So, you need to find $P(X>2)=\sum\limits_{r=3}^\infty P(X=r)$.  Using the formula to compute the probabilities that 3, 4, 5, ... deaths occurred and adding would be a pain.

The easiest way to find $P(X>2)$ is to use the formula
$$
P(X>2) = 1-\bigl(\,P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)\,\bigr),
$$
which says that the probability sought is 1 minus the probability that $X$ is not more than 2.

To calculate $P(X=0)$ use the formula with $m=4$ and $r=0$:
$$
P(X=0) = 4^0\cdot{e^{-4}\over 0!} =e^{-4}
$$

To calculate $P(X=1)$ use the formula with $m=4$ and $r=1$:
$$
P(X=1) = 4^1\cdot{e^{-4}\over 1!} =4e^{-4}
$$
And for $m=4$, $r=2$
$$
P(X=2) = 4^2\cdot{e^{-4}\over 2!} =8e^{-4}
$$
Thus
$$
P(X>2) = 1-P(X=0)-P(X=1) = 1-e^{-4}-4e^{-4} - 8e^{-4}\approx.7619.
$$

Can you handle the other two parts now?

Comment: Yes I can. Thank you so much! Are my answers for **i-a)** and **i-b)** correct tho?

Comment: @methusaleh You're welcome, glad to help. Yes, you did parts i-a) and b) correctly. I would calculate part i-b) as "two years and two deaths per year on average is 4 deaths on average over two years", though. For ii-c), your $m$ is 10 (five years, two per year), which you stated in part 11-c) correctly.